# Angular: serving application on custom context-root with npm start on localhost

Tags: angular, contextpath, ng-build, contextroot

I have an Angular application which starts on port 4300 with this configuration:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --port 4300 --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

The app is reachable to the url:

http://localhost:4300/#/index.html

I want to serve it on a context-root, like: "/myApp/"

The application has to start always with `npm start`, and I want to reach the url:

http://localhost:4300/myApp/#/index.html

How can I do it?

Everything I tried doesn't work:

- setting `<base href="/myApp/">` doesn't work
- setting `"build": "ng build --prod --base-href=myApp"` doesn't work

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can u share screenshot of your network tab ?

Comment: And the angular version  you are working on ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng build --prod --base-href /myApp/`, or same but with `ng serve`

I think the forward slashes are important here

Answer (score 1):

Add `baseHref`, `deployUrl` in your angular.json file. Adding code snippet:

```
"serve": {
     "options": {
        "baseHref": "/myApp/",
        "deployUrl": "/myApp/"
      }
    }
```

This `<base href="/myApp/">` will remain as is.

You can remove `--base-href=myApp` from the build command

Comment: ok, and what if I get HTTP 404 for assets like images etc?

Comment: Your assets will be served from same url.

Comment: @AlessandroC let me know, if it worked for you.

Comment: I managed to make it works: the app is served on the context-root, some assets gave 404 because there was a / character at the beginning (/assets/); on some other assets instead I was forced to keep the / character, othwerwise I had compilation error. Very strange.

Comment: If `baseHref` `deployUrl` helped, u can upvote my answer.